# Get all enum values via a Class<?> reference

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I am analyzing some fields of a class via reflection. If the type of a field is an enum type, I want to retrieve all values for this enum.

```
private MappedType mapType( final Class<?> c ) {
    ... 
    else if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom( field ))
         {

            //This code is not valid
            final Enum<?> e = (Enum<?>) c;
            Object[] possibleValues=e.values();
            ...
            return MappedType.ENUM;
         }
```

How to retrieve a list of all possible enum values? (String names of the values would be sufficient)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumMembers.html

Given a fully qualified name of an Enum class, you can find constants in it by

```
Class.getEnumConstants()
```

Assuming you are passing the Class of the field in field Variable, you can try as below

```
 else if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom( field ))
 {
        Object[] possibleValues=field.getEnumConstants();
  //...
 }
```

Comment: So simple, I should have known that ;-)

Comment: I want a generic approach. So, I used  Object obj = Season.SUMMER; System.out.println(obj.getClass().getEnumConstants()); Here instead of getting T[] in return I am getting hexcode & toString() hex also different than this. .length() is working file but not the list. Any idea?